# How do I prepare this system to add Ubuntu in a dual-boot setup with Win 7 on this single-drive laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation, windows-7

I am a new Linux user and am looking to add a Linux-based OS to learn on and I've chosen Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.  Win 7 is already installed.  Although I've backed up my Windows 7 data, I prefer to err on the safe side when it comes to potentially damaging the Windows install
[Here is my disk layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1S9l.jpg)

I have been trying to read as much content as I can in preparation for the last several months, including the dual-boot tags, disk partition / disk prep, boot loaders, etc.

From what I've read, Windows can spread or fragment data out and although GParted is more efficient, it has a higher chance of wrecking the Windows partition when shrinking it.  My questions are:

1) My plan is to use Windows Disk management to shrink the Windows Volume after defragging the drive.  Is that the best approach?  There is plenty of free space, and I probably will set aside about 20 GB for the system, 4 GB /swap, and maybe 10-20 GB for /home.

2) I've read that the system may not see the boot partition if it is not in the first 100 GB of the drive.  Based on my drive, should I preemptively create a /boot partition before the installation, or let Ubuntu try first?

3) Any other special considerations I should consider for this [system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Ozt.jpg)?

4) Should I just run Linux in Virtual Box first until I really get the hang of things?  What knowledge would I truly need before pursuing a true install?  My concern with running VM is performance limitations - I want to see how the system truly runs.  Thank you!

Comment: If you want to err on the side of caution and have about 100GB of external storage I would be inclined to make a system backup using something like the free version of Macrium Reflect or Clonezilla. You will not need a Swap partition, Ubuntu uses a swap file. Separate /home and / partitions are fine but problematic when you are only playing with 40GB or so in total. I’d go with a single partition. Don’t worry about a boot partition just let the Ubuntu installer do its thing. With your specs a VM will not give you the best experience. You might find something like Lubuntu is better overall

Comment: Thank you, @PonJar.  Regarding Lubuntu, were you referring to the experience specifically in VM, or in a live install?  I won't necessarily be running anything resource intensive except maybe to try some older games like OpenRA.  I am planning on possibly upgrading the RAM to 8 GB regardless.  I went ahead and ran a shrink volume and tried disk management after a defrag, and had > 200 GB available, even without disabling system restore or page file, etc.  I created a 100 GB partition, and I'm considering expanding it, as I've not run any Linux install at this point.

Comment: In my experience Lubuntu is one of the faster “main stream” distributions and quite suitable for a new Linux user. It depends on your hardware. My laptop is not the fastest and Lubuntu is noticeably faster than Ubuntu in a VM. When dual booting Linux has all the resources of the machine so it’s less likely to be an issue but Lubuntu may still have an edge that you would appreciate.